# How to write or create new data in Docker Writable Layer

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

I understand that each Docker container would have a writable layer to persist or save container related data. Even though it is epimeral, I would like to store my app data inside the container.

- How do I know the directory to store that (app) file?
- How does the [storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/) play a role?

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096  app
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096  mount
dr-xr-xr-x 13 root root 0  sys
```

When doing  `ls -lrt` inside my container I do see all the directories are not having the write permissions for the non-root user. Since I'm running my container as a non-root user I'm not sure how I can store the app data inside the container.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I know the directory to store that (app) file?

Any file written to a location which is not a [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) is written on the writable layer of the docker container file system.

---

> How does the storage drivers play a role?

As described [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/) :

> Docker supports the following storage drivers:
>
> overlay2 is the preferred storage driver, for all currently supported
>   Linux distributions, and requires no extra configuration. aufs is the
>   preferred storage driver for Docker 18.06 and older, when running on
>   Ubuntu 14.04 on kernel 3.13 which has no support for overlay2.
>   devicemapper is supported, but requires direct-lvm for production
>   environments, because loopback-lvm, while zero-configuration, has very
>   poor performance. devicemapper was the recommended storage driver for
>   CentOS and RHEL, as their kernel version did not support overlay2.
>   However, current versions of CentOS and RHEL now have support for
>   overlay2, which is now the recommended driver. The btrfs and zfs
>   storage drivers are used if they are the backing filesystem (the
>   filesystem of the host on which Docker is installed). These
>   filesystems allow for advanced options, such as creating “snapshots”,
>   but require more maintenance and setup. Each of these relies on the
>   backing filesystem being configured correctly. The vfs storage driver
>   is intended for testing purposes, and for situations where no
>   copy-on-write filesystem can be used. Performance of this storage
>   driver is poor, and is not generally recommended for production use.

So in most cases you would have to sue `overlay2`. Only if your machine is using `zfs` or `btrfs`, then you have the option of using the `zfs` or `btrfs`docker storage drivers. But then you'd better know how to manage those file systems. Use only those options if you want to benefit from snapshots.

---

> When doing  ls -lrt inside my container I do see all the directories are not having the write permissions for the non-root user. Since I'm running my container as a non-root user I'm not sure how I can store the app data inside the container.

In your Dockerfile, just make use of `RUN chown <your user> <location>`.

Answer (score 0):

Write data into the writable layer of the container and commit the changes to an image with different tag (OR) use the same container name to start the container.

Eg: Started one Ubuntu container and wrote some data into the file.

```
$ docker run --name elastic_spence -it ubuntu /bin/bash
root@5f4a60fb6348:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@5f4a60fb6348:/# mkdir data
root@5f4a60fb6348:/# cd data
root@5f4a60fb6348:/data# echo "Sample text" > data.txt
root@5f4a60fb6348:/data# ls -lrth
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12 Apr  9 17:06 data.txt
root@5f4a60fb6348:/data# cat data.txt
Sample text
root@5f4a60fb6348:/data#
```

Stopped the container and started the container with the same name.

```
$ docker start elastic_spence
elastic_spence
```

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
5f4a60fb6348        ubuntu                "/bin/bash"              2 minutes ago       Up 3 seconds                            elastic_spence
```

The file which was created in the previous session was persisted and is available in the new session.

```
$ docker exec -it 5f4a60fb6348 /bin/bash
root@5f4a60fb6348:/# ls
bin  boot  data  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@5f4a60fb6348:/# cd data/
root@5f4a60fb6348:/data# ls -lrth
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12 Apr  9 17:06 data.txt
root@5f4a60fb6348:/data# cat data.txt
Sample text
root@5f4a60fb6348:/data#
```

Additionally, you can commit the container changes to a new image like below.

```
$ docker commit elastic_spence datastore:1.0
sha256:9fd236a965f655b86c0b17588b7c87f823caaf6cd02eafb62457576e4e02b514
```

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
datastore                 1.0                 9fd236a965f6        4 seconds ago       88.9MB
```

Run the new image and you will able to see the persisted data.

```
$ docker run -it datastore:1.0
root@759a9a50b015:/# cat data/data.txt
Sample text
```